# Check for duplicates files on upload in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

With this asp net page upload file in C# I need check for duplicates files.

I accept 3 files in upload on the server.

This code worked and the duplicates file are not uploaded, but the alert popup is open only for the first duplicate file send to upload even when duplicates are more.

What's the problem ?

My code below, thank you in advance.

```
if (File.Exists(upload.FileName))
{
    DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("\\images\\"));

    FileInfo[] objFI = objDir.GetFiles("*.*");

    int iFileCnt = 0;

    if (objFI.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in objFI)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('This file exists " + upload.FileName + "');", true);
            iFileCnt += 1;
        }
    }                        
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire function? Like that I see a lot of meaningless things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `"Msg"` to the the `"Msg" + iFileCnt`. This changes the key for every iteration.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg" + iFileCnt, "alert('This file exists " + file.Name + "');", true);
```

Now alert execute more then once in loop.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now in duplicate file I have multiple open alert popup but the name of file is the same...

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Maybe you want print instead of `upload.FileName` this: `file.Name` in alert.

Comment: Thank you so much for help !

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
List<string> Filenames = new List<string>()
{
    "File1.jpg",
    "File2.jpg"
    //etc.
};

foreach(string s in Filenames)
{
    Upload(s);
}

private void Upload(string filename)
{
    string directory = @"\\path\\to\\directory";
    string fullpath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", directory, filename);

    if(File.Exists(fullpath))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg",     "alert('This file exists " + filename + "');", true);
    }
}
```