# How to Restrict File upload from a one instance of usercontrol, if same named file is already uploaded using different instance of same usercontrol

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I have a aspx page with two instance of same usercontrol for uploading files Say UC1 and Uc2. Usercontrol contains a fileupload control and a label showing uploaded file name.

While uploading file in UC2, I want to check if it is not uploaded already using UC1. I want to check this with file name stored in label inside UC1.

Is there any way to do javascript validation (for client side validation) for this which can be done in usercontrol scope, so that I can restrict file uploading there itself.

Comment: Do you want to check for duplicate files while upload?

Comment: @Prashant Pimple yes

Comment: Check [this](https://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst4290_Preventing-the-upload-of-duplicate-files-in-ASP-NET-C.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38611222/7124761)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that is not my case. in this it says one instance of fileupload is allowing to upload multiple files and checking duplicate within them. whereas my case is, there are two instance. Anyway I found the solution, I had to add an attribute  to the usercontrol as an onchange and check the duplication in aspx page level and not the usercontrol instance level.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need the file upload in all the uc instances. Why not add a boolean parameter in the uc called UseFileUpload. If the value is false, do not render the fileupload components

```
<uc:UserControl runat="server" ID="uc2" UseFileUpload="false" />
```

That is, if your usercontrol do something else than managing uploads.

If they don't, it would probably be easier if you only manage uploads with one usercontrol. After each upload, you could show to the user which document(s) he already uploaded and which ones he still need to upload

Comment: No they don't do anything else than managing uploads but they are like in different section as per user requirements so can't make it just one usercontrol for all the files.